# Android Tumblr Oauth-signpost 401

Tags: android, oauth, tumblr, signpost

Okay, so, I am making a Tumblr client for Android, I've been trying and failing to get OAuth working for about a week now. Here's how its going:

User fires up the app. Main activity's onCreate does this:

```
settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
authToken=settings.getString("OauthToken", "none");
authTokenSecret=settings.getString("OauthSecret", "none");
if(authToken=="none" || authTokenSecret=="none"){
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Authentication.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

this launches an authentication activity which contains a WebView. That activity successfully gets the request token, and sends the WebView to the Tumblr login screen. The user is asked to allow access to their data by the app, they press Allow, and my WebViewClient catches the Callback Url, and does this with it:

```
String[] token = helper.getVerifier(url);
            if (token != null) {
                try {
                    String accessToken[] = helper.getAccessToken(token[1]);
                    editor.putString("OauthToken", accessToken[0]);
                    editor.putString("OauthSecret", accessToken[1]);
                    editor.commit();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            finish();
```

The helper class's getAccessToken and getVerifier look like this:

```
public String[] getVerifier(String myUrl) {
    // extract the token if it exists
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(myUrl);
    if (uri == null) {
        return null;
    }

    String token = uri.getQueryParameter("oauth_token");
    String verifier = uri.getQueryParameter("oauth_verifier");
    return new String[] { token, verifier };
}

public String[] getAccessToken(final String verifier)
        throws OAuthMessageSignerException, OAuthNotAuthorizedException,
        OAuthExpectationFailedException, OAuthCommunicationException {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
                try {
                    mProvider.retrieveAccessToken(mConsumer, verifier);
                } catch (OAuthMessageSignerException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (OAuthNotAuthorizedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (OAuthExpectationFailedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (OAuthCommunicationException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
    }).start();
    return new String[] {
            mConsumer.getToken(), mConsumer.getTokenSecret()
    };
}
```

Then I finally go back to the main application screen and try to make my first API call, to get the most recent ten posts on the user's dashboard:

```
OAuthConsumer myConsumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(MainView.authToken, MainView.authTokenSecret);
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://api.tumblr.com/v2/user/dashboard?limit=10");
            myConsumer.sign(request);
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent()));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(line);
            }
```

However, instead of getting a nice JSON response like I ought to be, I am getting this:

```
10-20 16:36:18.110: D/Result(22817): {"meta":{"status":401,"msg":"Not Authorized"},"response":[]}
```

So where did I go wrong? Thanks

Comment: I am getting this exact same problem with I try to use API methods that require POST requests however, GET requests appear to work fine. I am starting to wonder if their API is a little flaky.

Comment: What version of android are you developing on?

Comment: I am also not able to get user information, event after getting the token and secret :(

it would be great if any one can give solution for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've successfully used signpost library with Appache HttpCommons GET/POST/PUTs.

Firstly, I've launched the WebView for login purpose, using the following code (`ActivityLogin.java`):

```
private static CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer consumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(AppConfig.CONSUMER_KEY, AppConfig.CONSUMER_SECRET);
private static OAuthProvider provider = new DefaultOAuthProvider (AppConfig.requestURL, AppConfig.accessURL, AppConfig.authURL);

private void logMeIn() throws ...{
    String authUrl = provider.retrieveRequestToken(consumer,AppConfig.CALLBACK_URL);
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(authUrl)));
}
```

Then, I've used `onNewIntent(Intent)` for receiving OAuth callbacks from the previously launched `Activity`:

`AppConfig.java` code snipet:

```
/** OAuth Authorization URL  */
public static final String authURL = mainOAuthUrl+"/authorize/?theme=android";

/** OAuth Request URL    */
public static final String requestURL = mainOAuthUrl+"/request/token/";

/** OAuth Access URL     */
public static final String accessURL = mainOAuthUrl+"/access/token/";

/** OAuth CALLback URL*/
public static final String CALLBACK_URL = "yourapp://twitt";
```

`ActivityLogin.java` code snipet:

```
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    Uri uri = intent.getData();
    if (uri != null && uri.toString().startsWith(AppConfig.CALLBACK_URL)) {  
        String verifier = uri.getQueryParameter(OAuth.OAUTH_VERIFIER);  

        provider.retrieveAccessToken(consumer, verifier);
        Data.OAuthAccessKey = consumer.getToken();
        Data.OAuthAccessSecret = consumer.getTokenSecret();
    }

}
```

And then, my connection code looks like that:

```
public HttpResponse sampleOauthConnect(String url) throws ...{

    /** setup some connection params */
    HttpContext context = new BasicHttpContext();

    HttpRequestBase request = new HttpGet(url);

    if (Data.OAuthConsumer == null)
        Data.OAuthConsumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(AppConfig.CONSUMER_KEY, AppConfig.CONSUMER_SECRET);

    if (Data.OAuthAccessKey == null || Data.OAuthAccessSecret == null)
        throw new LoginErrorException(LoginErrorException.NOT_LOGGED_IN);

    Data.OAuthConsumer.setTokenWithSecret(Data.OAuthAccessKey, Data.OAuthAccessSecret);

    try {
        Data.OAuthConsumer.sign(request);
    } catch (OAuthMessageSignerException e) {
        throw new LoginErrorException(LoginErrorException.OAUTH_EXCEPTION, e);
    } catch (OAuthExpectationFailedException e) {
        throw new LoginErrorException(LoginErrorException.OAUTH_EXCEPTION, e);
    } catch (OAuthCommunicationException e) {
        throw new LoginErrorException(LoginErrorException.OAUTH_EXCEPTION, e);
    }

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

    /** finally execute this request */
    return client.execute(request, context);
}
```

I may have missed something during copy-paste, just tell me if this solution will work for you. I'm using singpost 1.2.1.1

Comment: I do not have time to test your code right now, or even within the next couple days. But since the bounty was running out and it looks like a super helpful thorough post, you win! Thank you, I'll find out if it actually works later

Comment: Take in mind that I use two pair of keys right there : `AppConfig.CONSUMER_KEY, AppConfig.CONSUMER_SECRET` (which are stored in app), and `Data.OAuthAccessKey, Data.OAuthAccessSecret` which are generated by the server.

Comment: getting same response unauthorized:
{"meta":{"status":401,"msg":"Not Authorized"},"response":[]}

Comment: here is a full tutorial about Tumblr Login using signpost in android : http://www.android-ios-tutorials.com/920/tumblr-login-using-sign-post/

Answer (score 1):

Currently, Tumblr doesn't support `MultipartEntity`, so you have to use `NameValuePairs` to add params.

If you want to post a photo, you MUST convert that photo to an ARRAY and URL encode it!

Comment: Faced problem with photo posting. What do you mean by saying "...convert that photo to an ARRAY and URL encode it"? Could you provide some code snippet.

Comment: Tumbler's own library (Jumblr) uses multipart forms: https://github.com/tumblr/jumblr/blob/master/src/main/java/com/tumblr/jumblr/request/MultipartConverter.java